# How get rid of this message from cydia?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, error, cydia

I have been having trouble with this message. I cannot get any tweaks or anything from cydia anymore. How do i get rid of this message?

[image]

Comment: I'd imagine, based on the first bit, that you need to remove some of your installed packages because you have too many installed.

Comment: @timothymh, I have deleted almost every sources. I've kept only the original one that was there when you jailbreak and get the cydia, it comes with cydia. Other than that I have deleted everything. But still come up with this message. I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's sounds to me like it's talking about *packages* (e.g. tweaks and themes) rather than sources. Have you tried removing some of those? Also, do you have space on the drive?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is erase on source. That message is telling you you have too many packages from sources. Just delete on source.

Comment: I have done that and still have this message. I'm not sure why.